# VSCode does not Go to Definition unless using relative path

Tags: visual-studio-code

MacBook Pro 2019 - Catalina

I'm working on a create-react-app project which allows me to set an environment variable so instead of:

```
import { caseStudies } from '../../constants/containers/caseStudies';
```

I can simply write:

```
import { caseStudies } from 'constants/containers/caseStudies';
```

Which of course simplifies things a lot with not having to worry about paths so much.

However, right-clicking caseStudies and selecting Go to Definition, works on the first instance, but not the second, simplified instance.

I seem to remember this does work on Windows (haven't got a machine to check) so I'm wondering if it's a Mac problem?

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do that like this =>

## option one ->

1. Use Path Intellisense extension, make your own workspace config work
   with extension:
   https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=christian-kohler.path-intellisense
2. add custom workspace settings like

   ```
   {
     "path-intellisense.mappings": {
     "@app": "${workspaceRoot}/app"
     "@internals": "${workspaceRoot}/internals"
     }
   }
   ```

## option two ->

you create jsconfing.json in your project root and the content is ==>

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
 "target": "es2017",
 "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": false,
 "baseUrl": "./",
  "paths": {
   "Config/*": ["src/config/*"],
   "Components/*": ["src/components/*"],
   "Ducks/*": ["src/ducks/*"],
   "Shared/*": ["src/shared/*"],
   "App/*": ["src/*"]
 }
},
 "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

you can edit the setting to be like you wish Happy Coding :/: